# Java Script/jQuery – Simple if-statement not working with pre-defined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Sorry, I'm kind of new to this.

Is there a specific reason, why the if-statement in this snippet is not working? If yes, could somebody point me in the right direction?

```
var app = (function(){
   selector = {
       app: ".js-app",
       app__home: ".js-app__home"
   }

   foo();

   foo = function () {
     console.log(selector.app__home);
     if ($(selector.app).hasClass(selector.app__home)) {
        console.log("is home page")
     }
   }       
})();

$(document).on("ready", function() {
   app();
});
```

The first console.log()-output (the one outside the if-statement) works correctly though.
Thanks!

Comment: Does it work? for me.. foo is undefined at the time it tries to call that method... Please create a minimal example on JSFiddle demonstrating the issue. Also app method will execute instantly because of the ending `();`... remove them if you don't want to execute instantly.

Comment: `app` is executed directly and does not wait for the document to load. Since the IIFE in it doesn't return anything, `app()` should throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you find the updated code... 'foo' function called before its defined, so move the 'foo' function call after the 'foo' function definition ... and no need to use '.' on hasClass method... removed the '.' from app__home property...

```js
var app = (function(){
   selector = {
       app: ".js-app",
       app__home: "js-app__home"
   }

   foo = function () {
     console.log(selector.app__home);
     if ($(selector.app).hasClass(selector.app__home)) {
        console.log("is home page")
     }
   }      
   foo();
})();

$(document).on("ready", function() {
   app();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-app js-app__home">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! Indeed, it was the "." in the class name. Since hasClass required the class name without "." which caused the problem. Missed that one. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

`app` is not getting defined as a function. You have assigned an IIFE to `app`, that IIFE does not return anything explicitly, thus it returns `undefined` implicitly. Next, after document ready, you are trying to execute `app` assuming it to be a function. That's an error there.

Following should work:

```
var app = function(){
   var selector = {
       app: ".js-app",
       app__home: "js-app__home"
   }

   foo();

   var foo = function () {
     console.log(selector.app__home);
     if ($(selector.app).hasClass(selector.app__home)) {
        console.log("is home page");
     }
   }       
};

$(document).on("ready", function() {
   app();
});
```

While you are at it, define selector and foo using var or let or const, else you will make them global.

Comment: Thanks! It indeed was the "." in the class name! Thx!
I tried the var/const in front of "selector" but as soon as I added a second object, it threw the error "SyntaxError: Cannot use the keyword 'var' as a variable name.".


`var app = function(){`
`var selector = {`
      `app: ".js-app",`
       `app__home: "js-app__home"`
   `},` 
`var bar = {`
  `something: nice`
`}`
`}`

Comment: remove 
$(document).on("ready", function() {
   app();
});
from your code and see if that still works.